# Best way to transfer data between servlet and jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

**First try:**

I'm generating data in servlet and then set it in request as attribute and send that request to jsp by calling requestDispatcher as follows:

```
request.setAttribute("data",data);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/page.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Now access it in jsp and display data.

This works fine but everytime user refreshes page it gets an alert saying you are resubmitting the form and ask for confirmation. This is annoying.

**Second try:**

Put data in session and access that in jsp page. In this way session gets very heavy as the data amount is big.

So my question is **what is the best way to pass data from servlet to jsp?**
Here data is object list.

Comment: Just use GET instead of POST to *retrieve* data. See also servlets tag wiki page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first solution is the good one. Using the session to hold data specific to a single request is not a good practice. The fact that users get a confirmation message has nothing to do with the way data are passed from servlet to JSP. It has to do with the fact that the page they're looking at and refreshing was the result of a POST request.

Use the [Redirect after Post (or Post-Redirect-Get) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to avoid this problem.

For example, suppose you're saving a new product, and after the product is saved (using a POST request), you would like to display the product's category page. It would go this way:

1. submit the "Save product" form
2. store the product in database, adn get its category ID (456)
3. send a redirect to the URL productCategory?categoryId=456
4. the user automatically goes to the above URL
5. Get the data for the category 456 from the database
6. Put this data in a request attribute and forward the the productCategory.jsp page
7. User sees the product category page, with the new product he just saved. If he refreshes, it redisplay the category without confirmation, and without resubmitting the "Save product" form.

Comment: Can I Send data without displaying it in url? That is (as per you example) send `categoryId` to `productCategory` servlet but not in url. Because then user can see it in browser url and can play with it. So is there any solution to this?

Comment: No, you can't redirect and do a post. To hide it, you would need to do all this in AJAX, but it would only give you a false sense of security. Anyone can right-click your page, view its source, modify it and resubmit, even if using POST or AJAX requests. Just make sure at server-side that access is forbidden to users not authorized to view specific categories. You could encrypt/decrypt request parameters, but even then, you should make the protected resources really protected. Security through obscurity doesn't work.

Comment: @Mark: How exactly is it a problem to "play" with the request parameter? Would you like to prevent specific categories from being displayed to the user in question? Then that problem needs to be solved differently (even with POST that would still be a problem as the enduser is also able to "play" with parameters of the POST request!).

Comment: @BalusC: Yes I want to prevent specific categories from being displayed to the user.